# An efficient way to save parsed XML content to Django Model

Tags: python, xml, django, django-models, xml-parsing

This is my first question so I will do my best to conform to the question guidelines. I'm also learning how to code so please ELI5.

I'm working on a django project that parses XML to django models. Specifically Podcast XMLs.

I currently have this code in my model:

```
    from django.db import models
    import feedparser
    class Channel(models.Model):
        channel_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.channel_title

    class Item(models.Model):
        channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        item_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.item_title

    radiolab = feedparser.parse('radiolab.xml')
    if Channel.objects.filter(channel_title = 'Radiolab').exists():
        pass
    else:
        channel_title= radiolab.feed.title
        a = Channel.objects.create(channel_title=channel_title)
        a.save()


    for episode in radiolab.entries:
        item_title = episode.title
        channel_title = Channel.objects.get(channel_title="Radiolab")
        b = Item.objects.create(channel=channel_title, item_title=item_title)
        b.save()
```

radiolab.xml is a feed I've saved locally from [Radiolab Podcast Feed.](http://feeds.wnyc.org/radiolab)

Because this code is run whenever I python manage.py runserver, the parsed xml content is sent to my database just like I want to but this happens every time I runserver, meaning duplicate records.

I'd love some help in finding a way to make this happen just once and also a DRY mechanism for adding different feeds so they're parsed and saved to database preferably with the feed url submitted via forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it run every time, don't put it in models.py. The only thing that belongs there are the model definitions themselves.

Stuff that happens in response to a user action on the site goes in a view. Or, if you want this to be done from the admin site, it should go in the admin.py file.

Comment: Moved the parsing code to admin.py and it's still the same. Duplicate records.

Comment: You can't just dump it in a file anywhere. You need to put it in a function that will be called from an action in your admin.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but have no idea how to go about it because creating function means having it being called which will populate the database besides the first time I really need it to.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but you know what, forget the admin. Put it in a view and call it from a URL.